# Busy spin in CUDA

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, synchronization

How can I implement a busy spin mechanism of the form

```
while(variable == 0);
```

where variable is updated to 1 by some other CUDA thread after some event has occured.

I tried to just write it like above but the code just seems to get ignored and the calling thread just runs past it without waiting at all. I'm absolutely sure that the value is 0, but the thread does not wait at all.
Also, if I write:

```
while(variable == 0) __threadfence();
```

in order to not risk having the variable cached, the thread blocks indefinitely even thought the variable gets set to 1 eventually.
This is all very strange behavior to me, since replicating this code on the CPU produces the correct behavior.

Edit: Oddly, this seems to work correctly if I have blocks of 1 thread each, but not if I have several threads within one block. So threads from one block can see writes done by threads from other blocks, but not writes done by threads from the same block. Strange...

Comment: might be a good idea to include the code defining `variable`, as its declaration my lead to it being cache instead of the value re-retrieved each iteration etc. at least on a CPU side, these types or vars should be `volatile`, but I know almost nothing of CUDA so I'm not sure if its `volatile` behaves the same.

Comment: My problem in the first code sample is that, even though the variable is 0, the thread never blocks.

Comment: Similar problem was encountered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703443/inter-block-barrier-on-cuda. There is a little discussion about why spin-lock is not good on GPU

Comment: The question you pointed does shed some light, but not entirely. I still don't get why using this code between different blocks causes them to deadlock, even though the number of blocks is <= than the number of cores (meaning they execute concurrently). Don't all blocks have visibility to the global memory?

Comment: There is no guarantee that blocks execute concurrently, even if #cores > #blocks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Busy-spinning requires a lot of attention and you have to be really careful about it!

You have to keep in mind, that 32 threads, forming a warp work in perfect sync. If you encounter a branch, threads not taking it become disabled, until the threads executing the branch - exit from it. 
That is why, trying to busy-spin within a warp can lead to a deadlock: 31 threads will be waiting forever for the single, disabled thread to do its work.

Secondly, if you try to synchronise between blocks, you must know that both blocks are running in parallel. In theory, you don't know how many blocks are running; in practice, you can read the specs of your GPU and launch just as many as it can handle (there are some bugs in the driver and/or hardware, which can cause some problems too)

Thirdly, you have to remember that CUDA compiler tries to optimise. You have to set your shared or global variable as 'volatile' to ensure that it is always being read.