# cuda, dummy/implicit block synchronization

Tags: cuda, synchronization

I am aware that block sync is not possible, the only way is launching a new kernel.

BUT, let's suppose that I launch X blocks, where X corresponds to the number of the SM on my GPU. I should aspect that the scheduler will assign a block to each SM...right? And if the GPU is being utilized as a secondary graphic card (completely dedicated to CUDA), this means that, theoretically, no other process use it... right?

My idea is the following: implicit synchronization.

Let's suppose that sometimes I need only one block, and sometimes I need all the X blocks. Well, in those cases where I need just one block, I can configure my code so that the first block (or the first SM) will work on the "real" data while the other X-1 blocks (or SMs) on some "dummy" data, executing exactly the same instruction, just with some other offset.

So that all of them will continue to be synchronized, until I am going to need all of them again.

Is the scheduler reliable under this conditions? Or can you be never sure?

Answer (score 3):

You've got several questions in one, so I'll try to address them separately.

**One block per SM**

I asked this a while back on [nVidia's own forums](http://www.nvidia.com/content/forums/index.html#entry1426544), as I was getting results that indicated that this is not what happens. Apparently, the block scheduler will not assign a block per SM if the number of blocks is equal to the number of SMs.

**Implicit synchronization**

No. First of all, you cannot guarantee that each block will have its own SM (see above). Secondly, all blocks cannot access the global store at the same time. If they run synchronously at all, they will loose this synchronicity as of the first memory read/write.

**Block synchronization**

Now for the good news: Yes, you can. The atomic instructions described in Section B.11 of the [CUDA C Programming Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf) can be used to create a barrier. Assume that you have `N` blocks executing concurrently on your GPU.

```
__device__ int barrier = N;

__global__ void mykernel ( ) {

    /* Do whatever it is that this block does. */
    ...

    /* Make sure all threads in this block are actually here. */
    __syncthreads();

    /* Once we're done, decrease the value of the barrier. */
    if ( threadIdx.x == 0 )
        atomicSub( &barrier , 1 );

    /* Now wait for the barrier to be zero. */
    if ( threadIdx.x == 0 )
        while ( atomicCAS( &barrier , 0 , 0 ) != 0 );

    /* Make sure everybody has waited for the barrier. */
    __syncthreads();

    /* Carry on with whatever else you wanted to do. */
    ...

    }
```

The instruction `atomicSub(p,i)` computes `*p -= i` atomically and is only called by the zeroth thread in the block, i.e. we only want to decrement `barrier` once. The instruction `atomicCAS(p,c,v)` sets `*p = v` iff `*p == c` and returns the old value of `*p`. This part just loops until `barrier` reaches `0`, i.e. until all blocks have crossed it.

Note that you have to wrap this part in calls to `__synchtreads()` as the threads in a block do not execute in strict lock-step and you have to force them all to wait for the zeroth thread.

Just remember that if you call your kernel more than once, you should set `barrier` back to `N`.

**Update**

In reply to [jHackTheRipper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/470341/jhacktheripper)'s answer and [Cicada](https://stackoverflow.com/users/703016/cicada)'s comment, I should have pointed out that you should not try to start more blocks than can be concurrently scheduled on the GPU! This is limited by a number of factors, and you should use the [CUDA Occupancy Calculator](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CIIBEBYwAA&url=http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/CUDA_Occupancy_calculator.xls&ei=iD30T6m6MMf80QXLy-T6Bg&usg=AFQjCNG_VhxwvgVBBUZnnincdbTyvYLrKQ&sig2=Ks5m-Jq5frs92MxJhNmXFA) to find the maximum number of blocks for your kernel and device.

Judging by the original question, though, only as many blocks as there are SMs are being started, so this point is moot.

Comment: wow, it looks great! :) Just some questions since I saw many other attempts similar to this one but all of them were failing because memory incoherence or cached barrier. Have you tried it? @Pedro

Comment: @elect: Yes, I actually use this in my own code, albeit without the calls to `__syncthread()` since I only have 32 threads per block. If you're hesitant to take my word for it, you might want to check out Appendix A of "CUDA by Example: An Introduction to General-Purpose GPU Programming", in which atomic operations, mutual exclusion and synchronization between blocks are discussed.

Comment: Perfect, so I guess it is working as supposed to do, did you not experience any issue, did you? On which hw? Fermi or Kepler? OS and Cuda software version? I was going to ask you about what you mean exactly with "you have only 32 threads/block" but then I got it, you meant that because you have only a warp/block, right? However, I am going to give a read to that Appendix just in case I find something else. By the way, thanks for your comment and the code :)   @Pedro

Comment: @elect: I've used this in code that I have tested on devices of compute capability 1.3 and 2.0. Haven't gotten my hands on a Kepler board yet. I've been using CUDA version 4.1 and 4.2 on a Linux system, but that should have no effect. This approach depends only on the atomic instructions working as they should, i.e. atomically, and therefore should not depend on the specifics of the underlying hardware. Please do update your questions with the results if it works for you too!

Comment: Ok. I will update. Last question, because Nvidia forums are down right now, is this your Nvidia discussion you were referring to? http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:bfO8pj6kjAAJ:forums.nvidia.com/index.php%3Fshowtopic%3D232483+&cd=1&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=it @Pedro

Comment: @elect: Yes, that is the discussion.

Comment: -1 I'm sorry, but this is wrong! Please see jHackTheRipper's answer for an explanation.

Comment: What about the performance of such a atomic block sync. Just restarting a new kernel should not take that long. And the newer Cuda version can start multiple kernels "parallel" using unused blocks and as far as I know. This would reduce this possibility since the blocks are occupied by a loop.

Comment: @Cicada: I've updated the answer to address yours and jHackTheRipper's concerns.

Comment: @djmj: Yes, I've updated the reply to address that problem. You should not start more blocks than what can be scheduled by the device, and in Kepler, this may cause problems as the device may be shared.

Comment: @djmj I know, but I am running an algorithm that has to run thousand of cycles. In each of these cycles, I need different degrees of parallelization, that is sometimes I need only one block of 34 threads and sometimes N blocks (always of 34 t) with N [1,34]. The point is that each kernel call as an overhead between 3-20 µs on NOT WDDM systems (where they say it is much higher). And right now I do be on win7 ^^ . However, I hope to switch as soon as possible to linux in order to have such a lower overheads. In any case, it'd be nice to avoid them completely, maybe with just a kernel call! :p

Comment: @djmj Just want to update about kernel overheads in WDDM systems. They say no less than 40 µs (compare to the 3 µs). Likely to be higher.

Comment: @Pedro  Have you tested your code launching also a block-number bigger than the SMs?

Comment: @elect: Yes, this worked with up to eight times the number of SMs, which was the maximum number of blocks I could schedule synchronously. You should use the occupancy calculator to see what this would be for your code.

Comment: What you suggest is possible, but dangerous.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703443/inter-block-barrier-on-cuda?rq=1

Answer (score -4):

@Pedro is definitely wrong!

Achieving global synchronization has been the subject of several research works recently and, at last for non-Kepler architectures (I don't have one yet). The conclusion is always the same (or should be): it is not possible to achieve such a global synchronization across the whole GPU.

The reason is simple: CUDA blocks cannot be preempted, so given that you fully occupy the GPU, threads waiting for the barrier rendez-vous will never allow the block to terminate. Thus, it will not be removed from the SM, and will prevent the remaining blocks to run.

As a consequence, you will just freeze the GPU that will never be able to escape from this deadlock state.

*-- edit to answer Pedro's remarks --*

Such shortcomings have been noticed by other authors such as:
http://www.openclblog.com/2011/04/eureka.html

by the author of OpenCL in action

*-- edit to answer Pedro's second remarks --*

The same conclusion is made by @Jared Hoberock in this SO post:
[Inter-block barrier on CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703443/inter-block-barrier-on-cuda?rq=1)

Comment: No, I am not "definitely wrong", otherwise this would not work in my own code. I have added a comment regarding the maximum number of blocks, which addresses your concerns regarding deadlocks. As for the "several research works" saying this is not possible, could you point me to one or two of them?

Comment: this is not a matter of concurrently scheduled, but concurrently running blocks

Comment: How do you define concurrently running? You can *schedule* up to eight blocks per SM which will all *run* intermittently. While one block is spinning on the `while`-loop, the other blocks on the same SM can still run, filling the slots between each memory access. By the way, I'm still waiting for the "several research works".

Comment: A note at the top of a blog post on OpenCL, i.e. *not* CUDA. That's not exactly "several research works". Please try harder, or at least post a counter-example in which this fails. If you're going to call other people's answers "definitely wrong", you're going to have to do a bit more work.

Comment: you can schedule but they are not running in parallel! have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703443/inter-block-barrier-on-cuda?rq=1  the answer is from @Jared Hoberock, an nvidia fellow, I guess he's more aware than you are about how NVIDIA GPUs work...

Comment: OpenCL or CUDA it doesn't matter! this is a hardware limitation!

Comment: I think we may differ in our appreciation of the word "schedule". I'm using it in the way the CUDA Programming Guide does, i.e. assigned to an SM. As for Jared Hoberock's answer, he says it may not work in future hardware releases. It does, however, work now.

Comment: it definitely does not work on my GPUs! It is not reproducible because it relies on hardware mechanisms that neither CUDA nor OpenCL allow us to control. Thus it cannot be used for any serious application.

Comment: Wow, you implemented and ran a test that quickly? Please do post your code so we can all learn from it...

Comment: I tested it a year ago because I needed such a feature, that's why I knew it didn't work

Comment: You must have done a rather poor job then, because this does work for me. But I suggest we let this discussion be, as it's not quite evidence-based and I don't see it leading anywhere constructive. I'll leave it to the original poster to decide what works best for him/her.

Comment: Sure. As long as you keep on asserting a thing that @Cicada, Jared Hoberock, Matthew Scarpino's book and I demonstrated as impossible, I don't see it leading anywhere constructive neither.

Comment: After more than one year on Cuda, I am coming to the point that theory matters just until a certain point. I also thought that block sync was not possible after a lot of googling, but if Pedro says that it is working for him, I dont see why he should lie. Dont get me wrong, guys, I am not saying that one of you is right 100%, Im just saying that I am gonna give a try (as soon as I find some time to implement it :D ). I am sure that there are so many factor (both hw and sw) in the game and we should just figure out which of them matters. In any case, I will keep you both updated! :)  elect

Comment: @elect: when you find time, please try with different configurations and different GPUs. It should work with small configurations. By the way, I'll try to provide a complete benchmark as soon as I have time too.